# AutoLayout align label to the left of the view

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am new to autolayout, as in my problem when the uilabel text increase the other label which has text `nothing` disappear, when then text is small it appear

[image: when text is small]

[image: when text is large]

**Code**

```
// first label

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: 10, height: 50))
label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
label.numberOfLines = 0


view.addSubview(label)

label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

// end of first label


// label1

let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50))

label1.text = "nothing"
label1.numberOfLines = 0
view.addSubview(label1)

label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: label.intrinsicContentSize.width).isActive = true


NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

// end of label1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .leading,
relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label,
attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0,
constant: label.intrinsicContentSize.width).isActive = true
```

the constant value `label.intrinsicContentSize.width` makes the label disappears or goes out of screen  , consider that design

| 10 -leftLabel - 20 - nothingLabel - 10 |

and give nothingLabel **contentCompressionResistencePriority** to 1000